# Why do I keep getting the wrong output for my if statement JAVA

Tags: java, if-statement

i'm testing sides of a triangle to see if the triangle is a equilateral or isosceles, but even when all the values are equal I still get the else output. 
the code in question is at the bottom, i just included the rest for reference

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    System.out.println("  Triangle Calculator  \n");

    Scanner inputab = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Input lenghts of sides 'a' and 'b':");
    double sideA = inputab.nextDouble();
    double sideB = inputab.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Input the size of Angle C in degrees:");
    double angleC = inputab.nextDouble();
    inputab.close();

    double sideC = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(sideA, 2) + 
    Math.pow(sideB, 2)- 2*(sideA*sideB)*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angleC))));     

    System.out.println("\n\t   /\\\n\t  /  \\\n\t /    \\\n\t/      \\");
    System.out.printf("   %3.1f",sideA);
    System.out.print("/        \\");
    System.out.printf("%3.1f",sideB);
    System.out.println("\n      /          \\\n     /            \\\n    /______________\\");
    System.out.printf("\t  %3.1f\n", sideC);

    double angleA = Math.asin(sideA*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angleC))/sideC);

    angleA = Math.toDegrees(angleA);

    double angleB = 180 - angleC - angleA;

    double perimeter = sideA + sideB + sideC;

    double hf = 0.5 * (sideA + sideB + sideC);
    double area = Math.sqrt(hf*(hf-sideA)*(hf-sideB)*(hf-sideC));

    System.out.printf("\nSide a       = ");
    System.out.printf("%4.3f",sideA);
    System.out.printf("\nSide b       = ");
    System.out.printf("%4.3f", sideB);
    System.out.printf("\nSide c       = ");
    System.out.printf("%4.3f", sideC);
    System.out.printf("\nAngle A(Deg) = "); 
    System.out.printf("%5.3f", angleA  );
    System.out.printf("\nAngle B(Deg) = ");
    System.out.printf("%5.3f", angleB);
    System.out.printf("\nAngle C(Deg) = ");
    System.out.printf("%5.3f", angleC);
    System.out.printf("\nPerimeter    = ");
    System.out.printf("%5.3f", perimeter);
    System.out.printf("\nArea         = ");
    System.out.printf("%5.3f", area);


    if (sideA == sideB && sideA == sideC)
    {
        System.out.println("\nThis is an Equilateral Triangle");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("\nThis is not an Equilateral Triangle");
    }

    if ((sideA == sideB && sideB!= sideC ) 
       ||(sideA != sideB && sideC == sideA) 
       || (sideC == sideB && sideC != sideA))
    {
        System.out.println("\nThis is an Isosceles Triangle");
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("\nThis is not an Isosceles Triangle");
    }
```

Comment: Testing for exact equality when doing floating-point operations is probably the main problem. Instead of testing for equality, check to see if the absolute value of the difference between two values is smaller than some threshold.

Comment: if you want to get an exact value use `BigDecimal` instead of double, because for example if you input 4,4,60 sideC would evaluate to be 3.99999999999996 (32-32.00000000000004) instead of 4,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointy is correct. I ran eclipse in debugger mode to look at the values as the program executed. I used 5 for the values of sides A and B and 60 for angleC. The result was that A and B were equal to 5.0 while side C was equal to 4.9999...
There are multiple ways you could go about fixing this, but you seem capable, especially now that you know what the issue is.

Comment: If need any help beyond what I said please comment.